# Probability about confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

> Let $X_1,...X_n$ be iid $N(\theta,1)$. A 95% confidence interval for
>   $\theta$ is $\overline{X}\pm\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n}}$.Let p denote the
>   probability that an additional independent observation,$X_{n+1}$, will
>   fall in this interval.Is p greater than, less than, equal to .95?Prove
>   your answer.
>
> Casella & Berger, Chapter 9 - Interval Estimation

First $\overline{X}\approx N(\theta,\frac{1}{n})\Rightarrow Y=\sqrt{n}\overline{X}$~$N(\theta,1)$

I know that
$$P(\overline{X}-\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\theta\leq \overline{X}+\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n}})=0.95$$

$$P(\theta-\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\overline{X}\leq\theta+\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n}})=0.95$$
$$P(\theta-1.96\leq\overline{X}-\theta\leq\theta+1.96)=0.95$$
$$P(\theta-1.96\leq Y\leq\theta+1.96)=0.95$$

That's why I think it's the same, I tried other ways but got nowhere.

Someone give me a hint?

Comment: Smaller (to guess which one is correct, consider $n\to\infty$). What is your try?

Comment: @Did It is above what I tried.

Comment: ?? Sorry but where is $X_{n+1}$ in your approach?

Comment: @Did  assumed that $Y =X_{n+1}$, I not found another way to do this, since $\overline{X}$ is a random variable too.

Comment: I think you are being asked a question about 'prediction intervals' as in regression (but only estimating one parameter). The CI is based on the mean $\bar X = \bar X_n$ of $n$ observations. Now you have a question about an additional individual observation $X_{n+1},$ not before encountered. [By the way, translation note: I think you mean "Justify your answer." _Warrant_ is both a noun and a verb, somewhat different meanings. The verb is rarely used in the imperative, usually as a participle _warranted._ Slippery idioms on that one.]

Comment: @BruceTrumbo I have not learned regression, this is an inference problem, but I can not solve it

Comment: Clue must be in text somewhere ahead of problem. If I'm right about what's being asked, for prediction interval on next obs., variance is $\sigma^2(1 + 1/n).$

Comment: @BruceTrumbo This exercise is a homework so I do not know where it was taken, this is a discipline of inference

Comment: Looks as if someone else agrees what the question is. You gave it a try one way, why not show us what you can do with the variance in my last Comment. Either that, or somebody may come along and write it out for you. Hope you give it a try before that. –

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a little more than a hint but here goes...

The question appears to be asking if

$$\begin{align}
p = P\left\{\bar X - 1.96\sqrt\frac{1}{n} \le X_{n+1} \le \bar X + 1.96\sqrt\frac{1}{n} \right\} \\ 
 = P\left\{-1.96\sqrt\frac{1}{n} \le X_{n+1} - \bar X \le 1.96\sqrt\frac{1}{n} \right\} \\
\end{align}$$

is less than, equal to, or greater than $0.95$.

Now, it turns out $X_{n+1} - \bar X$ (itself a linear combination of normal random variables) is also normal, with mean $0$ and variance $1+\frac{1}{n}$ (due to independence of $X_{n+1}$ from the other $X_i$ and hence from $\bar X$).

Then we have that
$P\left\{ -1.96\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \le X_{n+1} - \bar X \le 1.96\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}  \right\} = 0.95
$
as well.

Now take a look at the interval above and notice that

$$ 
\left[ -1.96\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}, \ \ 1.96\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \ \right] 
= \left[ -1.96\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}, \ \ -1.96\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \ \right) \\
\bigcup \color{red}{ \left[ -1.96\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}, \ \ 1.96\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \ \right]} \\
\bigcup \left( 1.96\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}, \ \ 1.96\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \ \right]
$$

Can you deduce where $p$ stands relative to 0.95?